# json.load changing the string that is input

Tags: python, json, unicode

Hi I am working on a simple program that takes data from a json file (input through an html form with flask handling the data) and uses this data to make calls to an API.

**So I have some JSON like this:**

```
[{"id": "ßLÙ", "server": "NA"}]
```

and I want to send the id to an api call like this example:

```
http://apicallnamewhatever+id=ßLÙ
```

however when i load the json file into my `app.py` with the following command

```
ids = json.load(open('../names.json'))
```

json.load seems to alter the id from `'ßLÙ'` to `'ÃŸLÃ™'`

im not sure why this happens during json.load, but i need to find a way to get `'ßLÙ'` into the api call instead of the deformed `'ÃŸLÃ™'`

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  If Python 3, what is your locale set to when you call `open()`?

Comment: Your encoding might be windows-1252. `"ßLÙ".encode("utf8").decode("windows-1252")` --> `'ÃŸLÃ™'`

Answer (score 4):

It looks as if your `names.json` is encoded in `"utf-8"`, but you are opening it as `"windows-1252"` **[*]** or something like that. Try

```
json.load(open('names.json', encoding="utf-8"))
```

and you probably should also URL-encode the `id` instead of concatenating it directly with that server address, something along these lines:

```
urllib2.quote(idExtractedFromJson.encode("utf-8")
```

**[*]** Thanks @jDo for pointing that out, I initially guessed the wrong codepage.